# PDF generation as per PDF/X-1a:2001 standards using pdflib

Tags: java, pdf, pdf-generation, pdflib

I need guidance how I can generate a PDF complying to PDF/X-1a standards using PDFLib in java?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got answer after reading some of PDFLib examples, posting below one for your reference
[PDFLib Example](http://www.pdflib.com/pdflib-cookbook/pdfx/starter-pdfx3/)

You can use this to generate output related to your standard.